# Javamail : copy message to sent folder

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email with javamail api, and then copy it to sent folder.
I am using yahoo mail.
I can send the email, but the copy to sent folder doesn't work.

Here is the code to copy to sent folder :

```
private void copyIntoSent(Session session,Message msg) throws MessagingException{

        Store store = session.getStore("imap");
        store.connect("imap.mail.yahoo.com", SMTP_AUTH_USER, SMTP_AUTH_PWD);

        Folder folder = (Folder) store.getFolder("Inbox.Sent.Notifications");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);
        }
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        folder.appendMessages(new Message[]{msg});
    }
```

I am getting this exception :

> com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,
>   port: imap.mail.yahoo.com, 143; timeout -1;   nested exception is:
>     java.net.ConnectException: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai
>   d'attente

I don't know if the problem only comes from my settings of IMAP or if the method to copy to sent folder is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : send email code :

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
      // Setup mail server
      properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
      properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
      properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
      properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
      properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();      
         String filename = "SendAttachment.java";//change accordingly


         File f = new File("/path_to_file/test.pdf");
         MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
         attachmentPart.attachFile(f);


         Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();   
         multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
         message.setContent(multipart);
         // Send message
         Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
         transport.connect(host, from, pass);
         transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
         copyIntoSent(session, message);
         transport.close();
```

Comment: The yahoo [help page for their IMAP service](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mobile-mail/imap-server-settings-sln4075.html) says you have to connect on port 993 rather than the default 143, and that this is an SSL-based connection.

Comment: I have tried a telnet with 993 it doesn't work

Comment: Telnet won't cut it - the session needs to be encrypted with SSL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SSL with IMAP for Yahoo.  Set "mail.imap.ssl.enable" to "true".

Also, since you're using transport.connect explicitly, you shouldn't need to set "mail.smtp.host" and "mail.smtp.user"; and there is no "mail.smtp.password" property so you don't need to set that either.

And you should probably [change Sesion.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: thanks, it doesn't crash anymore with mail.imap.ssl.enable set to true. But the email is not copied into sent folder. Maybe the folder name "Inbox.Sent.Notifications" is not goot? I am french and using mail.yahoo.fr.

Comment: Is it copied into a folder named "Inbox.Sent.Notifications"?  Or does it fail to copy because the folder doesn't exist?  There's no standard name for the "sent" folder; you have to know what the name is that the user is using.  The name can be different for different users or different mail servers or different mail reader applications.

Comment: I don't know, and as I am french, I don't know if I need to use the french or english folder name. I think I am gonna use the cc solution

Answer (score 0):

From your exception it seems that your code is trying to connect to port 143 that's wrong use below settings for yahoo.

```
Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server
Server - imap.mail.yahoo.com
Port - 993
Requires SSL - Yes
```

And yes, imap allows 2-way synchronizing, which means everything you do remotely is reflected back in your Yahoo Mail account.so i don't think you externally need to move a mail to sent folder by default it will be reflected in sent mails of account

Comment: My emails are not automatically copied to sent folder, something must be wrong, or a setting has to be done in yahoo mail

Comment: are you able to send mail using this setting ?